# WxPython: type object 'Test' has no attribute 'openReportButton'

Tags: wxpython

I'm trying to enable a button on click of another button but it keeps giving me this error (see title)

```
class Test(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id, "Frame aka Window", style= wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.MINIMIZE_BOX, size=(400, 635))

        loadData = wx.Button(panel, label="Load Data", size = (100,40))
        loadData.SetFont(font)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.loadData, loadData)

        openReportButton = wx.Button(panel, label = "Open Report", size = (100,40))
        openReportButton.SetFont(font)
        openReportButton.Disable()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.openReport, openReportButton)

    def loadData(self, event):
        self.openReportButton.Enable()
```

What am I missing here?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make `openReportButton` an instance attribute (instead of just a local variable)

```
class Test(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id, "Frame aka Window", style= wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.MINIMIZE_BOX, size=(400, 635))

        loadData = wx.Button(panel, label="Load Data", size = (100,40))
        loadData.SetFont(font)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.loadData, loadData)
        # added "self."
        self.openReportButton = wx.Button(panel, label = "Open Report", size = (100,40))
        self.openReportButton.SetFont(font)
        self.openReportButton.Disable()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.openReport, openReportButton)

    def loadData(self, event):
        self.openReportButton.Enable()
```